# How to pass a MultipartHttpServletRequest?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Before posting this, I searched on stack overflow and did the applicable answer. I tried putting enctype on my form tag,

```
<form name="something" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

adding `MultipartResolver` on my bean,

```
<bean id="spring.RegularCommonsMultipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
```

but none of these solved my problem.

I want a method that accepts `MultipartHttpServletRequest` as the parameter. But the browser console gives me this error:

```
POST link.json 500 Internal Server Error
```

Eclipse on the other hand throws this error:

```
 Servlet.service() for servlet [action] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current request is not of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest]
```

My controller code looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping("myjson/myLink")
public void myMethod(MultipartHttpServletRequest request)
{

}
```

My code accepts `HttpServletRequest` and not `MultipartHttpServletRequest`. Is there other way to this?

I badly need `MultipartHttpServletRequest` because of its getFile method. I need to get an image from the client and store it on the server.

Comment: The error is the fact that your bean name is wrong. The bean named `spring.RegularCommonsMultipartResolver` must be named `multipartResolver` (it is one of the "magic" bean names in Spring). Next to that you shouldn't be using the request just obtain the `MultipartFile` directly by adding that as a parameter (which still won't work unless you rename the bean).

Answer (score 1):

This will surely work for you.

HTML:

```
<form action="myjson/myLink" id="fileForm" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="File"/>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/myjson/myLink", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String SaveFile(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("File") MultipartFile file) {
if(!file.isEmpty())
    {
        try
        {

            File convFile = new File(//here file location+filename);
            convFile.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
            fos.write( file.getBytes() );
            fos.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Spring Configuration:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver"/>
```

and in your Spring Initializer class Define MultipartConfigElement element

```
public class SpringInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SpringConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

     @Override
        protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration) {
            registration.setMultipartConfig(getMultipartConfigElement());
        }

        private MultipartConfigElement getMultipartConfigElement() {
            MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement = new MultipartConfigElement( LOCATION, MAX_FILE_SIZE, MAX_REQUEST_SIZE, FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD);
            return multipartConfigElement;
        }

        private static final String LOCATION = System.getenv("TEMP").replace('\\', '/') + "/"; // Temporary location where files will be stored

        private static final long MAX_FILE_SIZE = 5242880; // 5MB : Max file size.
                                                            // Beyond that size spring will throw exception.
        private static final long MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 20971520; // 20MB : Total request size containing Multi part.

        private static final int FILE_SIZE_THRESHOLD = 0; // Size threshold after which files will be written to disk

}
```